dummy output (no sound from internal speakers) Dell XPS 13 9315 ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I used to have ubuntu 20.04 LTS but on November 11 or, the day before, I decided to run the so classic
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Result was my internal speaker was not working anymore so I thought, in vain, that moving to 22.04 LTS would solve the problem.

This seems to be a cyclic problem which very few people have a glimpse on how to solve. Moreover none mentioned this solution on 20.04 and 22.04.
If your internal speaker was working before the updated chances are that it's all due to a deprecation of alsa configuration ( /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf )
to check this, try
journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"

In my case there was this part of text dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
when I checked my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
I had the following line :
options snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=1

after changing to :
options snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1

and rebooting my internal microphone was working once again.
I've scraped up pieces of information around the web to come up with this (stackoverflow, Dell tech support, askubuntu, reddit, superuser, linuxmint, gentoo)
Hope this will be useful to someone else in the future.

UPDATE : FIX for when you remove headset while on standby and wake up the machine :
If you do so you either encounter dummy output once again, or you get stuck with headset even though you've already unplugged it.
To avoid a reboot you have to force alsa to reload :
sudo alsa force-reload

In terminal you might see an error regarding the very line I said to change.
Frankly I have no idea why it complains, nonetheless it solves the issue.
